# Улучшить производительность php функций [startWith, endWIth]

Tags: php, оптимизация

Есть функции, которые проверяют начинается или заканчивается ли строка другой подстрокой:

```
public static function startWith (string $string, string $needle, bool $caseSensitive = false) : bool
{
    if($caseSensitive)
    {
        return mb_strpos($string, $needle) === 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return mb_stripos($string, $needle) === 0;
    }
}

public static function endWith (string $string, string $needle, bool $caseSensitive = false) : bool
{
    if($caseSensitive)
    {
        return mb_strrpos($string, $needle) === (mb_strlen($string) - mb_strlen($needle));
    }
    else
    {
        return mb_strripos($string, $needle) === (mb_strlen($string) - mb_strlen($needle));
    }
}
```

Но они слишком затратные, если ли варианты пооптимизированнее и чтобы поддерживало русский язык?

Спасибо.

Comment: `Но они слишком затратные` - в чём проявляется затратность?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по времени долго исполняются

Comment: @Андрей это мы все поняли, но на каких данных? Реальный пример в студию. И сколько мс он выполняется у вас и сколько вы ожидаете в идеале?

Comment: без какого-то бенчмарка, реального примера колоссальной затратности и тут можно впустую долго рассуждать. нужные конкретные данные, которые покажут реальные тормоза

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы посмотреть на бенчмарк. Может выложите где-нить, чтоб можно было их погонять локально?

А пока такой совет. **Если регистрозависимость не нужна**, то и локаль вас не интересует, а посему можно сравнивать строки как 8-битные. Для startWith отрежьте от оригинальной строки столько байт, сколько имеет в длину искомая строка. И просто сравните строки друг с другом. Для endWith сделайте тоже самое, но обрежьте исходную строку с конца.

Можно пойти дальше и перебирать байты исходной строки и сравнивать каждый с байтом искомой по тому же индексу. Сначала для startWith и с конца для endWith (можно буквально с конца к началу, а можно отступить от конца к началу на длину искомой строки и искать слева направо).